# Trouble loading spaces in a string with HTML field

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

The thing that I'm doing a login system. with additions, deletions and changes. I am using Java, Servlets, JSP also to use a connection to the MySQL handler, the problem arises when I want to display a string that contains spaces, eg

String to enter: Jorge Lopez

The string to display: Jorge

The strangest thing is that I put a textarea and shows me the chain correctly.

I tried replacing the \ n \ r does not work, in fact before the chain print and display correctly but when placed in the html field value it does not appear either.

I hope someone can help me

Comment: Could you post any code and the resulting HTML?

Comment: did you try to replace blank characters with "&nbsp;" ?
For example : "Jorge Lopez" => "Jorge&nbsp;Lopez"

Comment: use string1.remplaceAll("[\n\r]","");But no use, still shows only part of the chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `textarea`, you don't use the `value` attribute, but just place the text inside the `textarea` open and close tags

```
<textarea>Jorge Lopez</textarea>
```

And in an `input` text field, you must enclose the text in a `value` attribute with single `'` or double quotes `"`

```
<input type="text" value="Jorge Lopez"/>
```

With a dynamic JSP value, you would still wrap the value with quotes

```
<input type = "text" value="<%= usr.getName() %>" />
```

In HTML, you are allowed to [omit the quotes](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2). But then the value is restricted to certain characters only and must not contain white space.

In your case, the resulting text field looked like

```
<input type="text" value=Jorge Lopez />
```

which is interpreted as an attribute `value="Jorge"` and an attribute `Lopez` with no attribute value.

Comment: It is like writing a string in a textarea. You can only display the entire string in textarea, but in a normal field data only shows a chain. Ej. original string: "Hola mundo", in input text "Hola", in textarea "Hola mundo".I need to display in a field

Comment: @user1825955 What do you mean with "textarea chain"?

Comment: In the textarea shows me the full string. In a text field only shows me part of the string. example: original string: "Hola Mundo", String to display: "Hola"

Comment: I did not put a figure directly in the field, use Java session objects.
Example:
<input type = "text" value = <% = usr.getName ()%> />

Comment: Thanks that I was missing the "" Could you explain me why it happened that error

Comment: @user1825955 I updated the answer. I hope it explains the question.